# Verification of limit of $\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-verification

Does the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}$$ equal zero?

I definitely think no, because, the sequence is divergent as the the sequence is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^n2i=2^nn!$, which is divergent right? On the other hand, does Cauchy theorem on limits work here?

Comment: The product is probably $\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)$, otherwise the question is indeed trivial.

Comment: @uniquesolution yes, exactly

Comment: If so, then your argument is not relevant, because $\prod_{i=1}^n2i$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @uniquesolution but why? you mean the limit is zero?

Comment: because you are not computing the correct quantities. That's why. $\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)$ is NOT equal to $2^nn!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\prod_{i=2}^{n}(2i-2)\leq\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)\leq \prod_{i=1}^{n}2i,
$$
we have
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)}\geq \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}2i}=\frac{n!}{2^{n}n!}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}
$$
and
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)}\leq \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=2}^{n}(2i-2)}=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=2}^{n}2(i-1)}=\frac{n!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}.
$$
Since the right hand side of \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} tends to zero, the sandwich theorem implies that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)}=0.
$$

Comment: classic! the elementary sandwich I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

By the Stirling approximation, your product $$\frac{n!^2 2^n}{(2n)!}\approx\frac{2\pi n^{2n+1}(2e^{-2})^n}{\sqrt{4\pi n}2^{2n}n^{2n}e^{-2n}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}0.$$Or if you only want to know *that* it vanishes rather than how quickly, note that $$a_n:=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}\implies\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\to}\frac12,$$and in particular this ratio $<\frac{2}{3}$ for $n\ge 3$, so there's an exponentially decaying upper bound on $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Just consider for $a_n \frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}$ the quotient

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(2i-1)}\cdot \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}{n!} = \frac{n+1}{2n+1}\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{1}{2}$$

Now, you have for $N$ large enough vor all $n \geq N$:
$$a_n \leq C\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{n-N}$$

Comment: thanks, but where did you get $\frac{3}{4}$ term from, is it not $a_n\le C(\frac{1}{2})^{n-N}$?

Comment: @vidyarthi : We basically only need a $0 < q < 1$ with $a_n \leq C q^{n-N}$. So, since the quotient on the right approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ we are sure that for $n$ large enough the quotient will definitely be less than $\frac{3}{4}$. You could have chosen any $q$ with $\frac{1}{2} < q < 1$.

Comment: Besides this note that $\frac{n+1}{2n+1} = 1-\frac{n}{2n+1} = 1-\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{n}} > \frac{1}{2}$. So the quotient approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ from above.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^n(2i-1)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, 2^{-n} n!}{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$

Taking the logarithms, using Stirling approximation and continuing with Taylor series
$$\log(a_n)=-n \log (2)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (\pi )+\log
   \left({n}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{8
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ making $$a_n \sim 2^{-n}\sqrt{n \pi}$$

Try for $n=10$; the exact value is $\frac{256}{46189}\approx 0.00554245$ while the above approximation gives $\frac{1}{512} \sqrt{\frac{5 \pi }{2}}\approx 0.00547362$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}{n! \over \prod_{i = 1}^{n}\pars{2i - 1}}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n! \over 2^{n}\prod_{i = 1}^{n}\pars{i - 1/2}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n! \over 2^{n}\pars{1/2}^{\large\overline{n}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n! \over
2^{n}\bracks{\Gamma\pars{1/2 + n}/\Gamma\pars{1/2}}} =
\overbrace{\root{\pi}}^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{1/2}}}\
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n! \over
2^{n}\pars{n - 1/2}!}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n} \over
2^{n}
\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{n - 1/2}^{n}\expo{-\pars{n - 1/2}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}
\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{n + 1/2} \over
2^{n}
\braces{n^{n}\bracks{1 - \pars{1/2}/n}^{\, n}\expo{1/2}}} =
\root{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}{n^{1/2} \over 2^{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\root{\pi}\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over 2^{n +1}\root{n}} = \bbx{0}
\end{align}

> Note that
>   $\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 - {1/2 \over n}}^{n} = \expo{-1/2}}$.